# Count amount of characters in int

Tags: jquery, integer

I am looking for a way to count the amount of characters in an int in jQuery.

For example:

- 2314 returns 4
- 4 returns 1
- 435565 returns 6
- 22 returns 2
- 10 returns 2

Comment: Thanks for the update. Keep us posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var num=1234;
var count=num.toString().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three way to do it.
You can acieve it in three different ways
1) Conversion to string using `toString()`

```
var num = 123;
alert(num.toString().length);
```

2). Indirect conversion to string

```
var num = 123;
alert((num + '').length);
```

3) Using math operator.

```
var num = 123
alert(Math.floor( Math.log(num) / Math.LN10 ) + 1)
```